# DataTable returns old result

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, visual-studio-2013

i am making a c# aplication, im pretty sure my code is correct but im new to SQL connection with c#. My problem is that i have 2 objects in which A contains B and im executing a query to get all the A rows add them to a list and for each A row i go and search for it's B's and add them to A.bList. On the B query the results are A >.> what the heck is going on?

If it helps. The 2 classes are Owner and Dogs
So the class Owner(Dono) has a list of dog(Cao) objects.

```
    public class dal
{
    #region Membros
    private SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=canil;Integrated Security=True");
    private SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    #endregion

    #region MembrosGetSetPrivados
    private bool setCommand(string stringSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            cs.Open(); // Abre a Ligação
            // 1. Instancia o novo comando com a query e a connecção
            cmd = new SqlCommand(stringSQL, cs);
            // 2. Executa o comando
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //Fecha a ligação
            if (cs != null)
                cs.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
    private DataTable getCommand(string stringSQL)
    {
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(stringSQL, cs);
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    #endregion

    #region MembrosGetSetPublicos

    public void getDonos(List<Dono> lista)
    {
        DataTable resultados = getCommand("SELECT * FROM dono;");
        foreach(DataRow dr in resultados.Rows)
        {
            int idDono, contacto;
            string nome,morada;
            idDono = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
            contacto = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
            nome = dr[2].ToString();
            morada = dr[3].ToString();
            Dono dono = new Dono(idDono, contacto, nome, morada);
            getCaesDono(dono);
            lista.Add(dono);
        }
    }

    public void getCaesDono(Dono dono)
    {
        DataTable r = getCommand("SELECT cao.idCao,cao.idRaca,cao.chip,cao.peso,cao.nome,raca.descricao FROM cao,dono,raca WHERE cao.idCao = dono.idCao AND cao.idRaca = raca.idRaca AND dono.idDono = 1");
        foreach(DataRow linha in r.Rows)
        {
            int idCao = Convert.ToInt32(linha[0]);
            int idRaca = Convert.ToInt32(linha[1]);
            int chip = Convert.ToInt32(linha[2]);
            double peso = Convert.ToDouble(linha[3]);
            Raca raca = new Raca(idRaca,linha[5].ToString());
            string nome = linha[4].ToString();
            dono.caes.Add(new Cao(idCao, idRaca, chip, peso, raca, nome));
        }
    }
```

Well this fixes my problem, but i bealive it's wrong.

```
Dono dono = new Dono(idDono, contacto, nome, morada);
dal d = new dal();
d.getCaesDono(dono);
```

So clearly the problem is the SqlDataAdapter which seams to keep the last results. I can't seem to find any method to clear it or something. Should i use another SqlDataAdapter? I also think that isn't the answer. Can anyone point me the way?

Comment: Try to check if whether you have enabled cache somewhere

Comment: Hehe, yeah, but still that doesn't help me in any way, shape or form, so... yeah.

Comment: I searched for c# + sql + cache + disable but no clue. Can you point me the way please?

Comment: Are you using any static data?

Comment: Im sorry i don't know what you mean by static data, if by static data you mean static variables on the class then no, i am not. Actually the fields on each classe are all public and wide open =D. In the Database  all the tables are created using very basic sintaxe, only primary keys and foreign keys. Both those queries return what i expect on SQL server. I actualy bealive the cache thing might be the problem, i just don't know where to clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a global `DataTable` which is initialized only once. However, you don't seem to clear it between calls, so the old data remains in it. You need to either clear the tables or have the data adapter do it for you (clear before fill).

And: do *not* use an instance variable in `getCommand`! Do it like this:

```
private DataTable getCommand(string stringSQL)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stringSQL, cs))
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
}
```